# Need help installing Ubuntu from CD with no OS on the hard drive

Tags: installation

I downloaded and burned Ubuntu to a disk. When I try to install it the computer tells me "missing operating system". I changed the bios to boot from cd so that isn't the issue. Anyone have any ideas on how to make it work ?

Comment: It should work, but there isn't enough information in your question to really say what's wrong. Either your computer is not booting off the CD, or it didn't burn correctly.

Comment: the disk might be corrupted or the boot record damaged. can you change the flags on your boot sector to 'diag' and reboot? See if you can check if the disk is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Some burner software will burn ISO images as a file inside a file system.  This will cause the kind of failure you are seeing.

If you open the DVD on the system you burned it on you should see a number of directories with names like `boot`, `preseed`, and `install`.  This would indicate that the ISO file was burned correctly.

If you see one file with the name of the ISO image you downloaded, then the burner software burned the image incorrectly.

I usually use a USB key to boot my install systems.  There are a variety of tools which will take an ISO image and make a bootable USB image.  This works the same as if you had booted from a DVD.